# How to use "HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR" in Delphi

Tags: delphi, driver, hid

I have one `HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR` structure, How I can use this structure in Delphi 2010. I will copy here the full structure.

```
const unsigned char HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR[] =
{
    0x05,0x01,  //Usage Page (Generic Desktop Control)  
    0x09,0x02,  //Usage (Mouse) 
    0xA1,0x01,  //Collection (Application) 
        0x09,0x20,  //Usage (Stylus) 
        0xA1,0x00,  //Collection (Physical)
            0x15,0x00,  //Logical Minimum (0) 
            0x25,0x01,  //Logical Maximum (1)       
            0x75,0x01,  //Report Size (1) 
            0x95,0x01,  //Report Count (1)

            0x09,0x42,  //Usage (Tip SW) 
            0x81,0x02,  //Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)          
            0x09,0x44,  //Usage (Barrel SW) 
            0x81,0x02,  //Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)          
            0x09,0x32,  //Usage (In Range) 
            0x81,0x02,  //Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)          

            0x05,0x09,  //Usage Page (Buttons)          
            0x09,0x01,  //Usage (Button1)
            0x81,0x02,  //Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)
            0x09,0x02,  //Usage (Button2)
            0x81,0x02,  //Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)
            0x09,0x03,  //Usage (Button3)
            0x81,0x02,  //Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)
            0x09,0x04,  //Usage (Button4)
            0x81,0x02,  //Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)
            0x09,0x05,  //Usage (Button5)
            0x81,0x02,  //Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)

            0x05,0x01,  //Usage Page (Generic Desktop Control) 
            0x09,0x30,  //Usage (X)             
            0x65,0x13,  //Unit (inch)
            0x55,0xFD,  //Unit Exponent(-3) = 1000 lpi
            0x35,0x00,  //Physical Minimum (0) 
            0x46,0xF8,0x2A, //Physical Maximum (0x2AF8) 
            0x26,0xF8,0x2A, //Logical Maximum (0x2AF8)  = 11000         
            0x75,0x10,  //Report Size (16)
            0x81,0x02,  //Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)          

            0x09,0x31,  //Usage (Y) 
            // for A4 size (default)
            0x46,0x3A,0x20, //Physical Maximum (0x203A)
            0x26,0x3A,0x20, //Logical Maximum (0x203A) = 8250           
            // for LETTER size
        //  0x46,0x34,0x21, //Physical Maximum (0x2134)
        //  0x26,0x34,0x21, //Logical Maximum (0x2134) = 8500           
            0x81,0x02,  //Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)

        0xC0,   //End Collection            
    0xC0    //End Collection    
};
```

How I can use this structure in my HID Device. I got this structure from My HID Device vendor. Please give me more details about this structure. Thanks All

Comment: That structure is essentially a constant array of bytes: you may access it's content by index. What exactly would you like to do?

Comment: I guess, this would exceed a book. I would start e.g. here http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/

Comment: Ok,I have a HID Device (DigiMemo) its a Tablet kind device. I need to develop an application using this Device.So the problem is what ever I writing on the Device coming as Vertical but the same time the same content in the screen (my app window) coming as Horizontal. I described this issue to the device vendor. Then his reply was like `The DigiMemo can be used as a tablet and the working area is default in Horizontal. If you want change to Vertical, you need to write a driver to control it. (please find attached Document for HID Report Data Format.)' and also send the above file.

Comment: Are you sure you want to write your own device driver ? If yes, forget on Delphi.

Comment: No,I don't want to write my own device driver, I need to use existing device driver(DigiMHID.SYS,DIGIMHID.INF). But I don't understand where is the use of HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR structure. that is my issue. I'm poor in device driver side. Is I can use the Windows Api "HidD_SetFeature". Please correct me.

Comment: The question you asked is trivially answered, as Frederik has done. You actually need to ask a different question. I'm not sure what it is but it probably involves describing in a little more detail what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I would say, he wants to override HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR. This might solve the HidD_SetFeature function, but the question is when to call it.

Comment: Ok, How I can use the API function `HidD_SetFeature` in delphi 2010 effectively. Please explain the Parameters and usage. any effort should be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the only way how can I direct you is JEDI Jvhidcontrollerclass.pas unit, but I can't find any usable example. Maybe it's included in the pack. JEDI library has a good reputation at developers, so I hope this unit is not an exception. My own experience has been only with communication directly with drivers, not through HID, so maybe someone else will help you.

Comment: Yes,I'm using the `JEDI Jvhidcontrollerclass.pas`, through this class I can access all HID devices. So, I could use the `HidD_SetFeature` API function to override the HID feature. My basic need to change the `orientation` of HID Device Horizontal to Vertical. Thanks Very much...

Comment: @Able Isn't there lots of documentation on this at MSDN and the web in general? There may be precious little that is expressed in Delphi code but that's life at the bleeding edge! You need to know enough C/C++ to understand these APIs and then you can map them across to Delphi.

Answer (score 3):

```
const
  HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR: array[ <fill in length> ] of Byte = (
    $05, $01,
    $09, $02,
    ....
  );
```